# C# Logging when an app doesn't load due to missing DLLS

Tags: c#, windows-services

At work, I'm responsible for the maintenance of a number of windows services running on multiple servers. Invariably, something gets messed up and some dll or other isn't present when the service starts to load after I deploy, causing it to immediately terminate. Now, I realize that this SHOULD be fixed with a proper build and deployment process and not our current ghetto approach. We're working on that angle, but it still highlights a gap in my knowledge, which is why I'm asking here. Essentially, when this service failed to load, it didn't give any indication of what was wrong, including in the app log files (nlog). Is there a way to hook into a windows service application early enough in the app lifecycle to catch this sort of thing and log it somewhere (or alternatively, some other mechanism that already logs this) for troubleshooting?

The reason I ask is that I often deploy kind of late in the evening due to business constraints. I'd love to have something that quickly tells me how I screwed up, instead of sitting there trying to figure out which dll is missing, or which binding redirect is jacked up. I want to go home and drink a beer instead of playing wet nurse to a failing service. Anybody have any ideas about where I could bake this sort of thing in, so that I can send the aforementioned beer on to its maker?

Comment: Of course, no disrespect to ghetto people...

Comment: Of course not. One could make the statement that the current code is very spartan in the way that it handles things. It's just not at the place where I'd like it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Windows services crashes it usually writes some info about the error in the Windows EventLog. You could check there.

Otherwise, you should hook up your logger to the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event to catch any unhanded exceptions. Do that early enough and you might be able to log your errors.

If you know the errors are due to missing or wrong dlls, you can also catch those errors in the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) (aka Assembly Binding Log Viewer).

Quote from MSDN:

> The Assembly Binding Log Viewer displays details for assembly binds.
>   This information helps you diagnose why the .NET Framework cannot
>   locate an assembly at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Download the .NET developer SDK. In it you will find [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx). This is the viewer for the outputs from Fusion, which is the component responsible for resolving types. It will tell you what assembly is being looked for, in what sequence folders were scanned for the particular assembly, where it is attempted loaded from and why it has rejected a particular dll.

Answer (score 1):

While there is obviously no replacement for proper testing before deploy (i.e. simply using clean OS image on virtual machine would show lot of the issues)...

To detect and solve "assembly missing" failures enable fusion log and use it, check the blog post *[Fuslogvw.exe and diagnosing .NET assembly binding issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2006/07/12/663834.aspx)*. As stop-gap measure you can keep it enabled on all server (also I would recommend against doing it).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Windows Event Log, specifically the Application log, will tell you what is missing.